# Cannot set property 'boxShadow' of undefined - style in js

Tags: javascript, styles

I completlly don't know, why this code doesn't work. I've got a alert in console: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'boxShadow' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.el.addEventListener"*
My code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const card = document.querySelectorAll('.projects_pic');

    for(let el of card){
    
        el.addEventListener('mouseover',  () =>{
            this.style.boxShadow = "-1px 9px 40px -1px black";
        })
    }
    

});
```

Comment: What is the output if you print the content of `card` (`console.log(card);`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is refer to root document, pass parameter to your function and use `.target`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const card = document.querySelectorAll('.projects_pic');

  for (let el of card) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', (el) => {
      el.target.style.boxShadow = "-1px 9px 40px -1px black";
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="projects_pic">test</div>
<br>
<div class="projects_pic">example</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that `this.style` is `undefined`. 
Arrow function [binds context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), so `this` is not the element you are hovering on.
 Use `function(){/*content*/}` instead

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const card = document.querySelectorAll('.projects_pic');

    for(let el of card){
    
        el.addEventListener('mouseover',  function(){
            this.style.boxShadow = "-1px 9px 40px -1px black";
        })
        
    }
    

});
```

```css
div {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="projects_pic"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I changed this - e.target, and now is ok. I have to read about this on arrow function and this.